# convert resulting string datetime to dateTime value

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

i am fetching datetime value through xml like:

```
string time = "20150605020247+0000"
```

I want to convert into datetime value. I tried with `DateTime.Parse`, `ParseExact`, `Convert.ToDateTime`. It's not working, it's returning the error:

> string was not recognised as valid datetime

Comment: Please show what you tried for `ParseExact`, because that should work....

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve] of your progress so far.

Comment: thanks for your reply, actually i tried with ParseExact, but it was not working.DateTime theTime = DateTime.ParseExact(time2,
             "yyyy-MM-dd",
             CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
             DateTimeStyles.None);

Comment: string time = "20150605020247+0000";
    DateTime theTime = DateTime.ParseExact(time,
             "yyyy-MM-dd",
             CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
             DateTimeStyles.None);

Comment: Please put the code **in the question**.

Comment: @SiddarthVarunesh - as you can probably tell, `"yyyy-MM-dd"` is **not** the *exact* format of the value you have.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `DateTime.ParseExact`, since you know the exact format of the string. If we assume it's year, month, day, hour, minute, second, and offset, then you can do something like:

```
var result = DateTime.ParseExact("20150605020247+0000", "yyyyMMddHHmmsszzz", 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Be carefull!! The numbers behind + sign are most likely the UTC offset (the "zzz" specifier) and not the fractions ("ffff" specifiers).
Fractions are usually separated by dot sign; local time offset by plus sign. See my answer for correct format specifier: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54180752/2308106

Comment: Still not exactly correct. You need 3 z ('zzzz' format does not exist) and you need capital HH for hour - otherwise parsing will crash for hours above 12. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54180752/2308106

Comment: Thanks @Jan I should have remembered the uppercase `H` for 24-hour time. for some reason the 4 `z`'s worked, but I changed it to 3. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `DateTime.ParseExact` like this

```
DateTime theTime = DateTime.ParseExact(time,  "ddMMyyyyHHmmss+ffff,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use exact format specifier in your ParseExact method.

```
DateTime.ParseExact("20150605020247+0000", "yyyyMMddHHmmsszzz", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/cQJ9hN

**EDIT:**

Please check the standard DateTime formats used in .NET world: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings plus check the source of your data how exactly are the string dates produced.
However most likely the '+####' part of your string is the ***local date UTC offset***, not the fractions part of the time (as other answers suggest). So parsing the date by **using the "yyyyMMddhhmmssffff" would produce wrong results**.